# GitLab API Access: Failed to connect to internal API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, gitlab

I'm getting this error after I configured Gitlab on Arch Linux:

sudo -u gitlab bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production

```
Check GitLab API access: FAILED: Failed to connect to internal API
gitlab-shell self-check failed
  Try fixing it:
  Make sure GitLab is running;
  Check the gitlab-shell configuration file:
  sudo -u gitlab -H editor /usr/share/webapps/gitlab-shell/config.yml
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
```

unicorn.stderr.log:

```
INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
INFO -- : listening on addr=/run/gitlab/gitlab.socket fd=12
INFO -- : worker=0 ready
INFO -- : worker=1 ready
INFO -- : master process ready
INFO -- : worker=2 ready
```

Permissions:

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 gitlab gitlab 0 Jul 20 09:20 gitlab.socket
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab gitlab 6 Jul 20 09:20 unicorn.pid
```

gitlab-shell/config.yml

```
http+unix: "/run/gitlab/gitlab.socket"
gitlab_url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
```

gitlab/unicorn.rb

```
listen "/run/gitlab/gitlab.socket", :backlog => 1024
# listen "127.0.0.1:8080", :tcp_nopush => true
```

gitlab/gitlab.yml

```
host: localhost
port: 3000
https: false
```

nginx serverblock

```
server
{
        listen 80;
        server_name code.example.com;

        charset utf-8;

        location /
        {
                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                proxy_connect_timeout 300;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }

        server_tokens off;
}
```

I tried many things, nginx is showing a blank page or 502 Bad Gateway, and the gitlab check command is saying "Failed to connect to internal API" or "Error 500".

Comment: hi, do you have any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem.
What finally solved the issue was changing defaults:

increasing `unicorn['worker_processes']`

changing `unicorn['listen']` from `127.0.0.1` to the IP that GitLab listens on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

http+unix: "/run/gitlab/gitlab.socket"

try:

gitlab_url: "http+unix://%2Frun%2Fgitlab%2Fgitlab.socket"